# Docker volume on external hard drive

Tags: docker, flocker

I'm using a postgres image to run a container locally. 
I need to process a significant amount of data and I want to use an external hard drive for this. Is it possible to mount a volume on an external hard drive? Can I accomplish what I want with [Flocker](https://github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker)?

I'm using native docker for mac.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mount the external drive on your mac, and then go to the Docker icon -> preferences -> file sharing. Add your drive path to that list. Then when you do a `docker run -v /path/to/drive:/target myimage` it will mount your drive into your container (at /target in that example).

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know it would be so transparent. Upvoted for now and I will accept it when I test it.

Answer (score 3):

In Docker-for-mac, open up the preferences pane. Click on "File Sharing".

You can add the path to your external hard drive there, probably something like `/Volumes/Drive`.

You'll then be able to use that location as a host volume.

```
docker run -v /Volumes/Drive/mypostgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    --name some-postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
    -d postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer as of Automn 2023:

1. Mount the external drive on your mac
2. go to the Docker icon -> Settings -> Resources -> file sharing.
3. Add your drive path to that list. Then when you do a `docker run -v /path/to/drive:/target myimage` it will mount your drive into your container (at /target in that example).