# How do I have write privileges for Mounted Drives, External or otherwise for docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been working a lot with elasticsearch.  I have a huge issue with trying to expand my container HDD space.  I want to shift my volumes to an External HDD (NTFS or otherwise), but it seems that when I use docker-compose for something like:

```
volumes:
      - /Volumes/Elements/volume_folder/data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

It seems that it doesn't have write permissions. I confirmed it on Windows and Mac that this is the case, but I figured this is actually a common issue massively overcome with docker already. I have been looking but unable to do this.

How is this done?  I have Mounted (internal) Drives on my Windows 10 Machine I wanted to set up to store this data, as well as multiple External HDD I wanted to do the same.

I notice that I as the current user always have the r/w/e privileges to the Devices, so I was thinking that there was a way to have docker run as the current user for the purposes of determining Drive privileges?

The current issue is that a container falls outside the scope of the current user, and it seems that the external is something akin to 775.

Can someone assist with this?  I was looking on stackoverflow and all the mounts were based on the host machine, but NOT a different drive like this.  I can easily set a volume anywhere on the machine but when it comes to External HDD or H:/ or I:/, it seems to be a different story.

I was looking at this Stackoverflow question: [Docker volume on external hard drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005525/docker-volume-on-external-hard-drive) and I was looking into seeing what I can do.  When I looked at preferences, I saw that /Volumes was shared.  When I did `docker-compose up` it says that the system is readonly.  (Like previously stated).  It is 755.  Is there a way to run docker compose as a particular user?

*Edit*:  I was noticing that docker-compose allows a user option, and since I saw that the mounted HDD is owned by me.  I said create, maybe i can pass my user into each container and it will access it correctly.  I saw this article stating i could do this: https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15

I added user to each service, like this:  `user: ${CURRENT_UID}`

and then in the CLI, i put a couple different options:

```
CURRENT_UID="$(whoami)" docker-compose up
CURRENT_UID="$(id -u):$(id -g)" docker-compose up
```

The top one failed because the user was not in passwd, but the bottom one gave me a "permissions denied" error.  I was thinking it might have worked, but didnt.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [Error after moving Docker's dir to NTFS: overlayfs: upper fs does not support <xxx>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76481801/error-after-moving-dockers-dir-to-ntfs-overlayfs-upper-fs-does-not-support-x)

You may need to change the driver that docker is using to work with your filesystem.

You could use the VFS driver that has better compatibility but lower performance.